# Static assertion that a base pointer "equals" a derived pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-assert

Suppose I have a polymorphic hierarchy of classes with a common base:

```
struct Base { ~virtual Base() = default; };
```

I have inherited a large codebase which contains a long series of accessor functions (one for each derived type) that obtain a derived pointer via `reinterpret_cast`:

```
Derived * Get()       // Derived inherits from Base
{
    Base * b = lookup_derived();
    return reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(b);
}
```

Obviously the code should be using `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` (depending on whether the base is virtual). However, because this translation unit is large and the definitions of all the derived classes are jointly huge, the TU does not contain the definition of `Derived`, but only its declaration.

I would like to make this code more robust by adding to each derived class definition a static assertion that this reinterpret cast will produce the correct result. Essentially, I want something like this:

```
struct Derived : Base
{
    static_assert(static_cast<Derived *>(std::declval<Base *>()) ==
                  reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(std::declval<Base *>()));

    // ...
};
```

This constructions does not work of course since `declval` must not be evaluated, and the result of a reinterpret cast is not a constant expression. Is there any standard C++ mechanism to perform such a test statically? (The alternative would be a runtime check on `this` in the class constructor.)

**Edit:** Based on Aaron's post, I struck me that the question could be phrased entirely without reinterpret_casts:

```
static_cast<void *>(std::declval<Derived *>()) ==
static_cast<void *>(static_cast<Base *>(std::declval<Derived *>()))
```

Comment: It's pointless, you need run-time evaluation

Comment: Is what you are asking equivalent to : every Derived has Base as 'first' superclass?

Comment: @marom: It's kind of related to that, in the sense that in common ABIs being the first base means to have the same address as the more-derived object. But that's still an ABI detail.

Comment: I think this C++ standard proposal is relevant (it introduces `std::are_layout_compatible`): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0466r0.pdf

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I don't think that went anywhere, did it?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not that I can tell, which is sad because I happen to need exactly this feature, and it is not obvious how to implement it in a way which works even across all GCC versions for all data types.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will be good enough for the setup you have, but [this code on ideone](http://ideone.com/ReqjSO) works for me (clang 3.5.0 and  g++ 4.9.3).

*Updated to cast in the other direction, i,e. `Derived*`-to-`Base*`, to more closely match the question. And also updated to use `static_cast<void*>` explicitly instead of C-style casting and `reinterpret_cast` .*

```
template<typename D, typename B>
struct CheckCasting { 
    static D d_static;

    constexpr
    static B* bp = &d_static; // the original object is D,
                              // that allows us to static_cast both ways

    static
    constexpr bool static_equals_reinterpret() { 
        return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<D*>(bp)) 
            == static_cast<void*>(                bp );
    } 
};

struct Base { 
    constexpr Base() : i(0) {}
    int i;
};

struct derived_with_virtual : public Base { 
    derived_with_virtual() {}
    virtual void foo() { } 
};
struct without_virtual : public Base { 
    without_virtual() {}
};

static_assert( ! CheckCasting<derived_with_virtual, Base> :: static_equals_reinterpret()   ,"");
static_assert(   CheckCasting<without_virtual     , Base> :: static_equals_reinterpret()   ,"");
```

A few comments:

- I tried to replace the cast to `void*` with reinterpret_cast, but clang didn't like that. "note: reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression".
- I tried moving the `static_assert` inside the Derived class without success.
- This requires statically allocating an object for each Derived class.

Comment: (I've just done a quick edit to fix it for g++, was previously clang only)

Comment: Ah, thank you, this answer reminded me that I could phrase the question entirely in terms of static casts! Editing...

Comment: Clang refuses a cast in the other direction, `Base*` to `Derived*`, if attempted inside a constant expression. So maybe we're stuck with the other way around, which I guess is equivalent. But I don't know funky inheritance well enough to be sure it is equivalent, e.g. `virtual`-inheriticane. (*note: cannot cast object of dynamic type 'Base' to type 'derived_with_virtual'*)

Comment: (.. continued ..) just noticed that clang and g++ do accept a `Base*`-to-`Derived*` conversion in a constant expression, if it knows that the dynamic type of the original object is Derived. That's useful, but I have no idea how standard it is. If it's standard, then I think the only issue left is the requirement for a statically-allocated object which would be a problem if there is no default constructor

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Not only is no default constructor a problem, an abstract base class is a problem (it may have a default ctor but it can't be used on its own).